# How to access User meta data within a plugin

Tags: user-meta

I am trying to write a plugin. I have added an extra field in a registration form using the plugin successfully. I would like to check whether the value in the extra field matches any username already registered.

When I try to validate using the predefined usermeta functions. I get the below errors:

```
require( 'C:\wamp\www\cpa\wp-load.php' )
require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\cpa\wp-config.php' )
require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\cpa\wp-settings.php' )
```

I am able to do this in a theme template. But I would like to know how to access all the predefined functions of WordPress inside a plugin like we do in theme files.

Code:

```
//1. Add a new form element...

$referral_username = $_REQUEST['referral'];

add_action('register_form','myplugin_register_form');
function myplugin_register_form (){
    $referral_username = ( isset( $_POST['referral_username'] ) ) ? $_POST['referral_username']: '';
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="referral_username"><?php _e('Referral Username','mydomain') ?><br />
            <input type="text" name="referral_username" id="referral_username" class="input" size="20"value="<?php echo $referral_username = $_REQUEST['referral']; ?>" size="25" />



            </label>
    </p>
    <?php
}

//2. Add validation. In this case, we make sure referral_username is required.
add_filter('registration_errors', 'myplugin_registration_errors', 10, 3);
function myplugin_registration_errors ($errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email) {

    if ( empty( $_POST['referral_username'] ) )
        $errors->add( 'referral_username_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: You must include a Valid Referral User Name. Else leave it blank.','mydomain') );

    return $errors;
}

//3. Finally, save our extra registration user meta.
add_action('user_register', 'myplugin_user_register');
function myplugin_user_register ($user_id) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['referral_username'] ) )
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'referral_username', $_POST['referral_username']);
}


//Test Usermeta

$user = get_userdatabylogin('vijay');
echo $user->ID; // prints the id of the user;
```

Comment: You have listed 3 lines of PHP code, not error messages. What are the error messages you are receiving?

Comment: @CharlesClarkson  Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_userdata() in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\testplugin\testplugin.php on line 99

Comment: Code i am trying to add in the plugin file:
$user = get_userdatabylogin('vijay');
echo $user->ID; // prints the id of the user;

When i add the above code in the theme files, it works.

Comment: We will need to see the code that is producing the error. If it is in a function, show the whole function. If it is not in a function show lines from about 80 to 110 so we can see the code that surrounds the error as well as the line that reports the error. [Edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/113314/edit) with the code. Do not add it in a comment. All lines of code have to be indented 4 spaces (or a tab) to display correctly.

Comment: @CharlesClarkson I have added the code in the question. Please look at the last two lines of code. I am trying to print the id of the user. It works when used in the theme files but not inside the plugin. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Please look at the last two lines of code. I am trying to print the id of the user. It works when used in the theme files but not inside the plugin.

```
//Test Usermeta

$user = get_userdatabylogin('vijay');
echo $user->ID; // prints the id of the user;
```

In PHP, you cannot (normally) execute a user function before it has been defined.

The plugin is executing the `get_userdatabylogin()` code *before* `get_userdatabylogin()` has been defined as a function.

The theme is executing the `get_userdatabylogin()` code *after* `get_userdatabylogin()` has been defined as a function.

Consult the [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) (or a [WP Hooks database](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks) or search the WordPress code) to find the correct action name. Since you already know the code works in the theme, you should be able to use the [`after_setup_theme`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) action to run your code.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'test_user_meta' );
/**
 * Test User meta.
 */
function test_user_meta() {
    $user = get_userdatabylogin('vijay');
    echo $user->ID; // prints the id of the user;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to the top of the plugin file and re-test:

```
require (ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php');
```

Comment: This will break all other plugins which are trying to predefine pluggable functions. Never ever do that.

Comment: @toscho That's strange, I faced a similar issue with a plugin and after doing some research this is the solution that was suggested. I think it was on the Codex page too. So, it's not really the best way to do it!

Comment: Please ignore the Codex. There is a lot of misinformation.

Comment: @toscho Thanks for the alert! Too sad since it's the first reference for people like me with hardly any coding skills :(.